# Is there a free or open source virtual in-memory drive for Windows?

Tags: windows, virtual, drive

I'm developing an plug-in for a host program and I need to communicate with it with temporary files in the disk; if the temporary files are stored in an in-memory virtual drive the performance could be increased dramatically.

Hints for implementing an in-memory virtual drive in Delphi is also appreciated.

Comment: if The in-memory virtual drive program must be redistributable it'll be perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/27/free-ramdisk-for-windows-vista-xp-2000-and-2003-server/) one, it's based on a sample RAMDisk driver from MSFT, and appears to be configurable with a couple of registry tweaks.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find any information about redistribution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free edition of [VSuite Ramdisk](http://download.cnet.com/VSuite-Ramdisk-Free-Edition/3000-2122_4-10906583.html) that may meet your needs.